# JCaptcha4Struts2 plugin, image not loading

Tags: java, struts2, captcha

I'm pretty new to struts and i'm developing an application that uses captcha validatation. After a research for pre-built captcha plugins, i decided to go with **JCaptcha4Struts2**.

Soon i ran into series of troubles. I resolved all of them but i'm bot able to resolve this one.

I did everything as given in the demo application but in my application, the image is not showing up properly. Infact, only a black rectangle is appearing. These are the set of libraries i'm using:

- commons-collection-3.1
- commons-io-2.2
- commons-lang3-3.1
- commons-logging-1.1.3
- commons-logging-api-1.1
- freemarker-2.3.19
- ognl-3.0.6
- struts2-core-2.3.16.1
- xwork-core-2.3.16.1
- javax.mail-1.5.1 odbc7
- javassist-3.11.10.GA
- commons-fileupload-1.3.1
- jcaptcha4struts2-2.0.2
- struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.0
- jcaptcha-1.0
- jcaptcha-api-1.0
- imaging-01012005
- antlr-2.7.2

The development environemt i'm using is:
netbeans 8.0, jdk 1.8, java ee 7

Kindly help or suggest some other captcha option for struts2 ( considering that i'm very new to struts and project deadline is not very far).

EDIT: I read that struts 2.3.16 has some issues with imaging, so i had also tried struts 2.0.11 libraries

**JSP File**

```
<%@taglib prefix="jcaptcha"  uri="http://code.google.com/p/jcaptcha4struts2/taglib/2.0" %>
//some html code
    <s:form name="login" action="login" method="post">
         <s:textfield name="username" label="Username" size="20" autofocus="true" />
         <s:password name="password" label="Password" size="20" />
         <jcaptcha:image label="Enter the text" height="30" width="100"/>
         <s:submit name="submit" label="Submit" align="center" />
     </s:form>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="," />

    <package name="default" extends="jcaptcha4struts2-default">
        <action name="login"
            class="UserLoginAction"
            method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="jcaptchaDefaultStack"/>
        <result name="success">/profile.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/</result>
        <result name="login">index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/</result>
    </action>     

 </package>

</struts>
```

EDIT 2: I further tried using various permutations se versions of libraries (most of them being latest and now i'm getting exceptions. Here's the stacktrace

```
2014-04-07 16:15:25,874 DEBUG org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.debug:80 - Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jhlabs.image.WaterFilter.setAmplitude(D)V
    at com.octo.captcha.engine.image.gimpy.DefaultGimpyEngine.buildInitialFactories(DefaultGimpyEngine.java:59)
    at com.octo.captcha.engine.image.ListImageCaptchaEngine.<init>(ListImageCaptchaEngine.java:24)
    at com.octo.captcha.engine.image.gimpy.DefaultGimpyEngine.<init>(DefaultGimpyEngine.java:48)
    at com.octo.captcha.service.image.DefaultManageableImageCaptchaService.<init>(DefaultManageableImageCaptchaService.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at com.google.code.jcaptcha4struts2.core.beans.JC4S2Config.getDefaultImageCaptchaService(JC4S2Config.java:110)
    at com.google.code.jcaptcha4struts2.core.beans.JC4S2Config.getImageCaptchaService(JC4S2Config.java:82)
    at com.google.code.jcaptcha4struts2.core.actions.JCaptchaImageAction.getImageCaptchaService(JCaptchaImageAction.java:107)
    at com.google.code.jcaptcha4struts2.core.actions.JCaptchaImageAction.execute(JCaptchaImageAction.java:75)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: Problems with imaging?

Comment: @Lukasz Lenart  Struts 2.3.16 has divided an interface into two separate interfacesw, so many of the plugins have compatibility issues.

Comment: Ach right... but it should affect only plugins which provides themes

Comment: It's a very old plugin, I have asked if no objections to move it under GitHub and Strutsathon organisation - if ok, I'm going updated it to match the latest Struts release

Comment: @Lukaz Lenart I have decided to go with ReCaptcha. Thanks for showing your interest. And please do tell if you are able to resolve the problem asociated with the plugin.
ps: after suffling through a numerous library version, i finally got _some_ exception on my console

Comment: The problem is that "com.jhlabs.image" dependency isn't accessible any more

Comment: @LukaszLenart the plugin is working for older versions  of struts and other libraries, so i guess it should be because of some now depreciated classes like `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.jpegcodec`

Comment: But the error message states it clear: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jhlabs.image.WaterFilter.setAmplitude(D)V` which has nothing to do with Struts and got exact the same error when I tried build the plugin locally from sources

Comment: @LukaszLenart but the plugin is working fine with old libraries... check out the sample application that is provided on their website

Comment: Because it contains all the libs which aren't accessible nowadays ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JCaptcha library is really old, and going by the state of their code repository, it is an abandoned project.
The problem with this library is that it uses very specific version of [JH Labs Image filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) for CAPTCHA image distortion, and this version does not support JDK 1.8, it only supports 1.6.

But if you went with reCAPTCHA, it should not bother you anymore. Just decided to share my findings.

Comment: the problem has already been pointed out by @lukasz in the comments. I had to use `reCaptcha` at that time and the project has been closed. Thanks for your reply.